# How to set the video quality to low in Android Youtube API?

Tags: android-youtube-api

I am adding a function to play Android YouTube API to play videos in my app. The problem is that the video quality is automatically always set to highest quality available. But it causes lagginess when the internet is not good. Is there a way for me to set the quality to "auto" or specify a lower quality playback?